# How does GCC's 100% CPU usage avoid slowing Windows computers to a crawl?

Tags: gcc

Unsure if this question fits better here or at Superuser, but it's about GCC internals so here seemed better.

Most heavy computing tasks on Windows that show up in task manager as "100%" CPU usage make the whole user interface sluggish - keyboard inputs lag, the mouse stutters, switching windows is delayed, etc. My understanding of why this happens is that Windows responds to the high demand for CPU time by servicing UI tasks less frequently. Examples include complex image manipulation commands, websites with too many javascript-powered ads, complex matrix operations in matlab or numpy, etc. Many of these aren't even multithreaded and only max out a single core, but they still slow the computer.

But I've noticed that when compiling large projects with GCC, it pegs all CPU cores at 100% usage for minutes at a time, but the user interface remains completely smooth. I've noticed the same thing with both MinGW toolchains and arm-none-eabi toolchains. How is GCC able to avoid stepping on the toes of UI tasks while maintaining such efficient CPU usage? I'm aware the task manager CPU usage number is a bit of a lie to children, but there's clearly something GCC is doing differently despite trying to use all available resources.

Comment: As you might guess from the arm-none-eabi reference, I spend my time in the weeds with OS-less microprocessors, not giant pipelined x86 behemoths running modern OSes. Pardon any glaring misunderstandings, this isn't my home turf.

Comment: Most probably `large projects` and large projects spawn multiple processes, and heavy computing task is one.

Comment: @KamilCuk that seems likely (at the very least, these tasks have one thread doing most of the work, while GCC job threads are almost entirely independent and equal) but I'm still confused why that slows the UI. my intuition would be the opposite, that a heavy singlethreaded task would leave the system UI alone, as Windows is free to put UI tasks on the more idle cores.

Comment: I am not an expert on windows or inner workings of operating systems, but I think the unresponsiveness you saw is due to main memory filling up and the OS swapping to a file system and the 100% CPU usage you saw certainly didn't help but wasn't the real cause of the unresponsiveness. The OS can in theory have a lot of CPU intensive processes on its plate and still be responsive by just giving priority to the GUI in its process scheduler (Assuming preemptive process scheduling).